Math conference-organizing checklist?
I am intimately involved in the organization of a relatively high-profile conference. It's a special situation -- I don't want to get into it -- and we have essentially zero admin support. The conference will happen relatively soon; most things are set, but I would feel better to have some organizational structure to lean on. Can anyone share a conference-organizing checklist?
Edit: I just reread this, and I'm concerned that I have to do more to convince MO that I am not a troll; I am merely posting from a new account to avoid identifying myself. Here's an attempt: I am an early mid-career mathematician, and when I ask all the more-senior people around me who I know have organized lots of conferences, they don't have a lot to offer, as they have always done it with lots of administrative support. At the same time, I know that occasionally conferences, even big ones, are organized "by hand" --- but the people who know the most about the details are not usually the high-profile mathematicians who organize a lot of conferences. This post is addressed those unsung heroes, so to speak. It is an earnest plea. Details on visas and poster sessions welcome.

do you need to arrange accommodation, catering, will there be an online presence, do you need to acquire funding, financial support, ... without more details a helpful answer is difficult...

yes, yes, no, yes, yes. most of this is done. i'm interested both in broad categories and in details on what has to get done at the end.

@CarloBeenakker If you're easy to find and you have something that you might be willing to share but do not want to do it publicly, I'm happy to email you privately. I'm not really asking for brainstorm -- I have been to many conferences, know lots of people, have stormed a number of brains. I ideally want a checklist (such as one that has been created by a conference center, even) to feel more sure that we're not overlooking stuff.

A detailed checklist is here.
We organize many smaller conferences/workshops, where the participation of the participants is the key thing. No idea if that applies to this situation, but you might want to draw some inspiration from
overview of program elements
how to promote diversity
